# Negative PSRR of Two-Stage Op Amp

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, integrated-circuit, cmos

From page 4-9 of this lecture note https://pallen.ece.gatech.edu/Academic/ECE_6412/Spring_2004/L180-PSRR-2UP.pdf, it gives example on how to model a Two-Stage Op Amp to find the PSRR- when \$V_{Bias}\$ is connecting to ground as oppose to when \$V_{Bias}\$ is connecting to \$V_{ss}\$. One thing I don't understand is why \$r_{ds7}\$ is modelled differently given that it is connecting \$V_{out}\$ and \$V_{ss}\$ in both cases?

Also, not sure why \$C_{gd5}\$ is not included in the model with \$V_{Bias}\$ is connecting to \$V_{ss}\$ while \$C_{gd7}\$ was added? although it doesn't make any difference to the results.

Reference:
CMOS analog circuit design. Authors: Phillip E. Allen, Douglas R. Holberg.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sUL4FI-nVKIDNd4GdlbpYT66IsyoACoR/view pg.307-309

Comment: Off-site links go dead all the time. Please extract the relevant citations from the lecture note etc, and paste them as images into the question, giving proper credit. Or, even better, re-type the stuff you'll be citing - it'll be much easier to search, and to copy-paste and edit into an answer, so you'll help us help you that way :)